# How to create a next button with tkinter to switch between multiple frames

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, global-variables

I am writing a quiz program in tkinter that has a frame for each question being asked. After the user selects the correct answer from a radiobutton list, a window pops up allowing the user to select any of the questions in the quiz. Here is an example:
[image]

Instead of showing all of the possible answers, I'd like to have just a "next" and "previous" button but I'm having difficulty creating a button that would self update every time the next or previous button was selected.

Here is my complete code below for reference. I've highlighted the important parts afterwards to make it a little easier.

```
Root_File_Name = "C:\\LearningArabic\\LiblibArriby\\"
def Part1():
    JSON_File = Root_File_Name + "Lessons\\Lesson_1\\"
    with open(JSON_File+"Arabic_Lesson_1.json", "r", encoding = "utf-8-sig") as question_file:   
        data = json.load(question_file)

    def create_widgets_in_first_frame():        # Create the label for the frame
        current_frame=frames[0]               #Make the frame number generic so as to make copy/paste easier. ##UPDATE PER QUESTION##
        question_number = "question0"
        question_frame_populator(current_frame, question_number)

    def create_widgets_in_second_frame():
        current_frame=frames[1]               #Make the frame number generic so as to make copy/paste easier. ##UPDATE PER QUESTION##
        question_number = "question1"
        question_frame_populator(current_frame, question_number)

    def create_widgets_in_third_frame():
        current_frame=frames[2]               #Make the frame number generic so as to make copy/paste easier
        question_number = "question2"      
        question_frame_populator(current_frame, question_number)

    def create_widgets_in_forth_frame():
        current_frame=frames[3]               #Make the frame number generic so as to make copy/paste easier
        question_number = "question3"
        question_frame_populator(current_frame, question_number)

    def create_widgets_in_fifth_frame():
        current_frame=frames[4]               #Make the frame number generic so as to make copy/paste easier
        question_number = "question4"
        question_frame_populator(current_frame, question_number)

    def create_widgets_in_sixth_frame():
        current_frame=frames[5]               #Make the frame number generic so as to make copy/paste easier
        question_number = "question5"
        question_frame_populator(current_frame, question_number)

    def question_frame_populator(current_frame, question_number): #This is what displayes all of the information on the frame
        questionDirectory = data["lesson 1"]["part one"][question_number]       ##UPDATE PER QUESTION##  This is the directory for the question.
        wronganswer = questionDirectory["wronganswer"]                      #This is the directory for the wrong answers
        question = questionDirectory.get("question")                        #This is the question text            
        correctanswer = questionDirectory.get("answer")                     #This is the answer for whichever question has been selected.
        arabic = questionDirectory.get("arabic")                            #This is the arabic text for the question
        transliteration = questionDirectory.get("transliteration")

        global var
        var = IntVar()
        var.set(0)  #Sets the initial radiobutton selection to nothing

        answers = generate_answers(wronganswer, correctanswer)  #Pulls answers generated from the "generate_answers" function
        choices = []
        for i in range(3):
            choice = Radiobutton(current_frame, image=answers[i], variable = var, value=i+1, command= Check_Answer)
            choice.image = answers[i]
            choices.append(choice)

        random.shuffle(choices) #This line of code randomizes the order of the radiobuttons. 
        choices[0].grid(row=1, column=0)
        choices[1].grid(row=1, column=1)
        choices[2].grid(row=1, column=2)

        L1 = Label(current_frame, text=question, font=("Helvetica", 35))    #This displays the question at the top of the screen
        L1.grid(columnspan=4, row=0)

        transliteration_button = Button(current_frame, text="Show Transliteration", command= lambda: Transliteration(current_frame, arabic, transliteration))    # Makes the phonetic pronunciation button. #####
        transliteration_button.grid(column=0, row=2)

        Previous_Button() # Creates the "previous" button and displays it.
        Next_Button()  # Creates the "next" button and displays it.
        Quit_Button(current_frame)  # Creates the "quit" button and displays it.

    def Transliteration(current_frame, arabic, transliteration):
        Transliteration = Label(current_frame, text="'"+arabic+"'" + " is pronounced " + "'"+transliteration+"'", font=("Helvetica", 35))
        Transliteration.grid(row=3, columnspan=4)

    def generate_answers(wronganswer, correctanswer):
        Wans=random.sample(wronganswer, 2)
        images = [os.path.join(ImagePath, f"{Wans[i]}.png") for i in range(2)]
        images += [os.path.join(ImagePath, f"{correctanswer}.png")]
        answers = [PhotoImage(file=images[i]) for i in range(3)]
        return answers

    def Check_Answer():
        global lives
        global score

        if str(var.get()) !="3":
            special_frames[1].grid_forget() #This is the frame for right answers
            special_frames[0].grid(column=1, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=(tkinter.W, tkinter.E)) #This is the frame for wrong answers
            lives -=1

            Incorrect = Label(special_frames[0], text ="That's incorrect!\n Lives: " +str(lives) + "\n Score: " + str(score), font=("Helvetica", 35))
            Incorrect.grid(row=0, rowspan=2, column=0, columnspan=3)

        if str(var.get()) == "3":
            score +=1

            special_frames[0].grid_forget() #This is the frame for wrong answers
            special_frames[1].grid(column=1, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=(tkinter.W, tkinter.E)) #This is the frame for right answers

            Correct = Label(special_frames[1], text = "    That's right!    \n Lives: " +str(lives)+ "\n Score: " + str(score), font=("Helvetica", 35))
            Correct.grid(row=0, rowspan=2, column=0, columnspan=5)
            first_frame_button = Button(special_frames[1], text = "Question 1", command = call_frame_1)
            first_frame_button.grid(column=0, row=3)
            second_frame_button = Button(special_frames[1], text = "Question 2", command = call_frame_2)
            second_frame_button.grid(column=1, row=3)
            third_frame_button = Button(special_frames[1], text = "Question 3", command = call_frame_3)
            third_frame_button.grid(column=2, row=3)
            forth_frame_button = Button(special_frames[1], text = "Question 4", command = call_frame_4)
            forth_frame_button.grid(column=4, row=3)
            fifth_frame_button = Button(special_frames[1], text = "Question 5", command = call_frame_5)
            fifth_frame_button.grid(column=0, row=4)                
            sixth_frame_button = Button(special_frames[1], text = "Question 6", command = call_frame_6)
            sixth_frame_button.grid(column=1, row=4)

    def all_frames_forget():
        for i in range(6):  #This is for question frames
            frames[i].grid_forget()
        for i in range(3):  #This is for special frames, like the correct and incorrect answer frames
            special_frames[i].grid_forget()

    def check_remaining_lives(create_widgets_in_current_frame, current_frame):
        if lives<= 0:
            Zero_Lives()
        else:
            create_widgets_in_current_frame
            current_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=(tkinter.W, tkinter.N, tkinter.E))

    def Zero_Lives():
        special_frames[2].grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=(tkinter.W, tkinter.E))

        L5 = Label(special_frames[2], text="You have no remaining lives. \nPlease quit the lesson and try again.", font=("Helvetica", 35))
        L5.grid(columnspan=4, row=0)

        quit_button = Button(special_frames[2], text = "Quit", command = root_window.destroy)
        quit_button.grid(column=1, columnspan = 2, row=2)

    def Previous_Button():
        previous_button = Button(special_frames[1], text = "Previous", command = previous_question)
        previous_button.grid(column=1, row=5)

    def previous_question():
        global frameNumber
        frameNumber -=1
        call_frame_frameNumber()

    def Next_Button():
        next_button = Button(special_frames[1], text = "Next", command = next_question)
        next_button.grid(column=2, row=5)

    def next_question():
        global frameNumber
        frameNumber +=1
        call_frame_frameNumber()

    def Quit_Button(current_frame):
        quit_button = Button(current_frame, text = "Quit", command = quit_program)
        quit_button.grid(column=4, row=4)

    def quit_program():
        root_window.destroy()

    def call_frame_1():
        all_frames_forget()
        create_widgets_in_current_frame = create_widgets_in_first_frame() #This line is unique
        current_frame = frames[0]     #This line is unique
        check_remaining_lives(create_widgets_in_current_frame, current_frame)

    def call_frame_2():
        all_frames_forget()
        create_widgets_in_current_frame = create_widgets_in_second_frame() #This line is unique
        current_frame = frames[1] #This line is unique         
        check_remaining_lives(create_widgets_in_current_frame, current_frame)

    def call_frame_3():
        all_frames_forget()
        create_widgets_in_current_frame = create_widgets_in_third_frame() #This line is unique
        current_frame = frames[2] #This line is unique         
        check_remaining_lives(create_widgets_in_current_frame, current_frame)

    def call_frame_4():
        all_frames_forget()
        create_widgets_in_current_frame = create_widgets_in_forth_frame() #This line is unique
        current_frame = frames[3] #This line is unique         
        check_remaining_lives(create_widgets_in_current_frame, current_frame)

    def call_frame_5():
        all_frames_forget()
        create_widgets_in_current_frame = create_widgets_in_fifth_frame() #This line is unique
        current_frame = frames[4] #This line is unique         
        check_remaining_lives(create_widgets_in_current_frame, current_frame)

    def call_frame_6():
        all_frames_forget()
        create_widgets_in_current_frame = create_widgets_in_sixth_frame() #This line is unique
        current_frame = frames[5] #This line is unique         
        check_remaining_lives(create_widgets_in_current_frame, current_frame)       

    ##### Program starts here  #####
    Lesson1_FilePath = Root_File_Name + "Lessons\\Lesson_1\\"
    ImagePath = Lesson1_FilePath + "Images\\"

    root_window = Tk() # Create the root GUI window.
    root_window.title("Lesson 1: Part 1") # Label the root GUI window.

    global score
    score = 0               #Setting the initial score to zero.
    global lives
    lives = 3               #Setting the initial number of lives.
    global frameNumber
    frameNumber = 1

    window_width = 200      # Define window size
    window_heigth = 100

    frames = []  # This includes frames for all questions
    for i in range(6):
        frame=tkinter.Frame(root_window, width=window_width, height=window_heigth)
        frame['borderwidth'] = 2
        frame['relief'] = 'sunken'
        frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=(tkinter.W, tkinter.N, tkinter.E))
        frames.append(frame)

    special_frames=[] #This includes the frames for: wrong answers, right answers, and zero lives
    for i in range(3):
        special=tkinter.Frame(root_window, width=window_width, height=window_heigth)
        special['borderwidth'] = 2
        special['relief'] = 'sunken'
        special.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=(tkinter.W, tkinter.E))
        special.grid_forget()
        special_frames.append(special)

    call_frame_1() #Calls the first function which creates the firist frame

    root_window.mainloop()
```

I know it's a lot of code but I wanted to make sure everything was there in case something wasn't making sense to you all. Here are the parts that I think are the most important:

```
    def Previous_Button():
        previous_button = Button(special_frames[1], text = "Previous", command = previous_question)
        previous_button.grid(column=1, row=5)

    def previous_question():
        global frameNumber
        frameNumber -=1
        call_frame_frameNumber()

    def Next_Button():
        next_button = Button(special_frames[1], text = "Next", command = next_question)
        next_button.grid(column=2, row=5)

    def next_question():
        global frameNumber
        frameNumber +=1
        call_frame_frameNumber()

    global frameNumber
    frameNumber = 1
```

The problem is that python isn't recognizing "call_frame_frameNumber" as "call_frame_X" where X is changing each time the button is pressed. I get the error: NameError: name 'call_frame_frameNumber' is not defined

I know defining global variables isn't the best practice but it's all I really know at this point. If you can show a better way I'm more than willing to learn!

Comment: You really should learn about Python lists and in general, loops, before doing this. Normally you'd just have an index which points to a frame in a list, and then pressing a button would either increase or decrease the index and so the image would change.

Comment: @purpleice, could you be a little more specific? What parts of the code do you think would benefit from loops? What did you have in mind?

Comment: Functions `create_widgets_in_x_frame` could be rewritten as a single function. Besides, judging from the code you already know how to move forward/backward using indexes, so I don't see what problem you're having, just switch the frames the same way you switch questions.

Comment: @purpleice that's a great suggestion. The reason I hadn't done so yet was because I didn't know how to iterate the question number. Any recommendations?

Comment: @PurpleIce, thanks for the direction. I was able to figure my problem out with your help! Posted my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing some comments by @PurpleIce and trying to further clean up my code, I found a solution to my problem.

I changed the code so that there wasn't a unique call_frame_X for each question but just one general call_frame with a variable of frameNumber as shown below.

```
    def Next_Button():
        next_button = Button(special_frames[1], text = "Next Question", command = next_question)
        next_button.grid(column=0, columnspan=5, row=3)

    def next_question():
        global frameNumber
        frameNumber +=1
        call_frame(frameNumber)
```

Then, instead of having multiple create_widgets_in_X_frame, I created one general function that would iterate each time the "Next" button was selected.

```
    def create_widgets_function(frameNumber):
        current_frame=frames[frameNumber]               #Make the frame number generic so as to make copy/paste easier. ##UPDATE PER QUESTION##

        question_number = "question"+ str(frameNumber)
        question_frame_populator(current_frame, question_number)

    def call_frame(frameNumber):
        all_frames_forget()
        create_widgets_in_current_frame =create_widgets_function(frameNumber)
        current_frame = frames[frameNumber]
        check_remaining_lives(create_widgets_in_current_frame, current_frame)
```

This helped reduce/consolidate a lot of my code while simultaneously giving me a "Next" button.

Here is the updated code: 
    def Part1():

```
    JSON_File = Root_File_Name + "Lessons\\Lesson_1\\"
    with open(JSON_File+"Arabic_Lesson_1.json", "r", encoding = "utf-8-sig") as question_file:   
        data = json.load(question_file)              

    def create_widgets_in_first_frame():        # Create the label for the frame
        current_frame=frames[0]               #Make the frame number generic so as to make copy/paste easier. ##UPDATE PER QUESTION##
        question_number = "question0"

        question_frame_populator(current_frame, question_number)

    def question_frame_populator(current_frame, question_number): #This is what displayes all of the information on the frame
        questionDirectory = data["lesson 1"]["part one"][question_number]       ##UPDATE PER QUESTION##  This is the directory for the question.
        wronganswer = questionDirectory["wronganswer"]                      #This is the directory for the wrong answers
        question = questionDirectory.get("question")                        #This is the question text            
        correctanswer = questionDirectory.get("answer")                     #This is the answer for whichever question has been selected.
        arabic = questionDirectory.get("arabic")                            #This is the arabic text for the question
        transliteration = questionDirectory.get("transliteration")

        global var
        var = IntVar()
        var.set(0)  #Sets the initial radiobutton selection to nothing

        answers = generate_answers(wronganswer, correctanswer)  #Pulls answers generated from the "generate_answers" function
        choices = []
        for i in range(3):
            choice = Radiobutton(current_frame, image=answers[i], variable = var, value=i+1, command= Check_Answer)
            choice.image = answers[i]
            choices.append(choice)

        random.shuffle(choices) #This line of code randomizes the order of the radiobuttons. 
        choices[0].grid(row=1, column=0)
        choices[1].grid(row=1, column=1)
        choices[2].grid(row=1, column=2)

        L1 = Label(current_frame, text=question, font=("Helvetica", 35))    #This displays the question at the top of the screen
        L1.grid(columnspan=4, row=0)

        transliteration_button = Button(current_frame, text="Show Transliteration", command= lambda: Transliteration(current_frame, arabic, transliteration))    # Makes the phonetic pronunciation button. #####
        transliteration_button.grid(column=0, row=2)

        #Previous_Button() # Creates the "previous" button and displays it.
        Next_Button()  # Creates the "next" button and displays it.
        Quit_Button(current_frame)  # Creates the "quit" button and displays it.

    def Transliteration(current_frame, arabic, transliteration):
        Transliteration = Label(current_frame, text="'"+arabic+"'" + " is pronounced " + "'"+transliteration+"'", font=("Helvetica", 35))
        Transliteration.grid(row=3, columnspan=4)

    def generate_answers(wronganswer, correctanswer):
        Wans=random.sample(wronganswer, 2)
        images = [os.path.join(ImagePath, f"{Wans[i]}.png") for i in range(2)]
        images += [os.path.join(ImagePath, f"{correctanswer}.png")]
        answers = [PhotoImage(file=images[i]) for i in range(3)]
        return answers

    def Check_Answer():
        global lives
        global score

        if str(var.get()) !="3":
            special_frames[1].grid_forget() #This is the frame for right answers
            special_frames[0].grid(column=1, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=(tkinter.W, tkinter.E)) #This is the frame for wrong answers
            lives -=1

            Incorrect = Label(special_frames[0], text ="That's incorrect!\n Lives: " +str(lives) + "\n Score: " + str(score), font=("Helvetica", 35))
            Incorrect.grid(row=0, rowspan=2, column=0, columnspan=3)

        if str(var.get()) == "3":
            score +=1

            special_frames[0].grid_forget() #This is the frame for wrong answers
            special_frames[1].grid(column=1, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=(tkinter.W, tkinter.E)) #This is the frame for right answers

            Correct = Label(special_frames[1], text = "    That's right!    \n Lives: " +str(lives)+ "\n Score: " + str(score), font=("Helvetica", 35))
            Correct.grid(row=0, rowspan=2, column=0, columnspan=5)

    def all_frames_forget():
        for i in range(6):  #This is for question frames
            frames[i].grid_forget()
        for i in range(3):  #This is for special frames, like the correct and incorrect answer frames
            special_frames[i].grid_forget()

    def check_remaining_lives(create_widgets_in_current_frame, current_frame):
        if lives<= 0:
            Zero_Lives()
        else:
            create_widgets_in_current_frame
            current_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=(tkinter.W, tkinter.N, tkinter.E))

    def Zero_Lives():
        special_frames[2].grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=(tkinter.W, tkinter.E))

        L5 = Label(special_frames[2], text="You have no remaining lives. \nPlease quit the lesson and try again.", font=("Helvetica", 35))
        L5.grid(columnspan=4, row=0)

        quit_button = Button(special_frames[2], text = "Quit", command = root_window.destroy)
        quit_button.grid(column=1, columnspan = 2, row=2)

    def Quit_Button(current_frame):
        quit_button = Button(current_frame, text = "Quit", command = quit_program)
        quit_button.grid(column=4, row=2)

    def quit_program():
        root_window.destroy()

    def Next_Button():
        next_button = Button(special_frames[1], text = "Next Question", command = next_question)
        next_button.grid(column=0, columnspan=5, row=3)

    def next_question():
        global frameNumber
        frameNumber +=1

        call_frame(frameNumber)

    def create_widgets_function(frameNumber):
        current_frame=frames[frameNumber]               #Make the frame number generic so as to make copy/paste easier. ##UPDATE PER QUESTION##

        question_number = "question"+ str(frameNumber)
        question_frame_populator(current_frame, question_number)

    def call_frame(frameNumber):
        all_frames_forget()
        create_widgets_in_current_frame =create_widgets_function(frameNumber)
        current_frame = frames[frameNumber]
        check_remaining_lives(create_widgets_in_current_frame, current_frame)

    def call_frame_1():
        all_frames_forget()
        create_widgets_in_current_frame = create_widgets_in_first_frame() #This line is unique
        current_frame = frames[0]     #This line is unique
        check_remaining_lives(create_widgets_in_current_frame, current_frame)        

    ##### Program starts here  #####
    Lesson1_FilePath = Root_File_Name + "Lessons\\Lesson_1\\"
    ImagePath = Lesson1_FilePath + "Images\\"

    root_window = Tk() # Create the root GUI window.
    root_window.title("Lesson 1: Part 1") # Label the root GUI window.

    global score
    score = 0               #Setting the initial score to zero.
    global lives
    lives = 3               #Setting the initial number of lives.
    global frameNumber
    frameNumber = 1

    window_width = 200      # Define window size
    window_heigth = 100

    frames = []  # This includes frames for all questions
    for i in range(6):
        frame=tkinter.Frame(root_window, width=window_width, height=window_heigth)
        frame['borderwidth'] = 2
        frame['relief'] = 'sunken'
        frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=(tkinter.W, tkinter.N, tkinter.E))
        frames.append(frame)

    special_frames=[] #This includes the frames for: wrong answers, right answers, and zero lives
    for i in range(3):
        special=tkinter.Frame(root_window, width=window_width, height=window_heigth)
        special['borderwidth'] = 2
        special['relief'] = 'sunken'
        special.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=(tkinter.W, tkinter.E))
        special.grid_forget()
        special_frames.append(special)

    call_frame_1() #Calls the first function which creates the firist frame

    root_window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't great coding practice as the amount of frames will increase but you could just use several 'if' statements to call on each function.

For example:

```
if frameNumber == 1:
    call_frame_1()
```

Comment: Or they could just do it properly and rewrite their function to be `call_frame(frame_numfer)` so there will be no unnecessary if ladder and a ton of functions that all do same thing.

Comment: Yep, "this isn't great coding practice as the amount of frames will increase...".